# How to append dyanmic url pattern at the beginning of fixed tail in django urls?

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to give AJAX call to dyanmic urls in django to serve images. An individual profile can have it's own photos. Then team of individuals will display photos of all members and main page may highlight different random images from different teams. So, I can have following set of urls in django:

1. ^home/images/
2. ^home/teams/1/images/
3. ^home/teams/1/user/2/images/

I'll be using AJAX request to send details like team id, user id etc. So, there'll be only one view that'll handle any request related to viewing images. How can I route all above url request to this single view with single url pattern.
To be specific, How can I construct dynamic urlpattern in django which will allow me to append '/images/' to any url at the run time? Means visitor should be routed to the same view whether he visits any of the above url?
If there is any flaw in my logic or approach, please correct me as I am not expert in django. I'm using django 1.9 version.

Comment: Write three patterns and point'em onto a single view.

Comment: Post your lookup code. How do you get the required object given the user_id and team_id? If you already have that implemented then you can route all these to the same view. If you're using DRF then you can implement a reusable ImageViewMixin as a detail action route and reuse in your views

Comment: Thanks solved the issue. Followed suggestion by @IvanStarostin . Created 3 different url paths and pointed them to single view.